# Liquibase for multiple databases(Spring-boot)

Tags: spring-boot, liquibase, liquibase-hibernate

I have multiple databases in springboot application.
I am using liquibase configuration for automatic updation for databse.I configured master.xml file.

```
<databaseChangeLog

xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"

xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"

xmlns:ext="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext"

xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog    

http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.1.xsd

http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext     
http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-ext.xsd">

 <include file="scripts/seven/table1.sql"      
 relativeToChangelogFile="true"/>
  <include file="scripts/seven/table2.sql" 
  relativeToChangelogFile="true"/>


  </databaseChangeLog>
```

The above configuration is working for only when i have single database.

If we have multiple databases what is the procedure for liquibase configuration to update the tables with respective of databases.

Comment: Do you use maven?  If you do, you may use `liquibase-maven-plugin` for multiple databases.

Comment: have a look at [this](https://www.jeejava.com/how-to-setup-liquibase-in-spring-for-multiple-datasources/). You have to create two master.xml files and configure the path in your application.properties